# Metal Refractive Index

Tags: optics, reflection, refraction, complex-numbers

I'm working on the Fresnel equation for the calculation of the reflection of a light (532 nm) on Iron.

I've got a question: Is metal's [refractive index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refractive_index) always a real number or it can be a complex number?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Metals refractive index is always a complex number (and not only for metals). The imaginary part shows the [extinction coefficient $k$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beer%E2%80%93Lambert_law) -that expresses the absorption in a material.
 Real and imaginary parts are not connected.
P.S. For engineering calculations the real part is sometimes [less than 1](http://www.opticsinfobase.org/view_article.cfm?gotourl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.opticsinfobase.org%2FDirectPDFAccess%2F6C06CA18-E618-3E36-855E55E02D1C9ADA_140787%2Foe-15-17-10744.pdf%3Fda%3D1%26id%3D140787%26seq%3D0%26mobile%3Dno&org=).
Theoretically, even for Fresnel reflection in a *dielectric* we must use the full formula including the complex part:

### Normal case (90 deg):

$R=\frac{(n-1)^2+k^2}{(n-1)^2+k^2}$

 For dielectrics (glasses) in visual diapason $k<<1$ so we don't use it, but you got metal.

Comment: Thanks sir. You mean for Iron, I should use the both parts ( real and imaginary ) ? can tell me the both parts for Iron?

Comment: Sir, did you see the link? :)

Comment: Got it, thanks.  n = n +Ki. OK? is ti true?

Comment: I don't know precisely your metal thickness but I can look for coefficients at work tomorrow.

Comment: Sir, is it true : n = n + ki

Comment: n(complex)=n+i*k, yes

Comment: Sir, I've read Fresnel equation. As you said I should use the complex form of the number. so then how can I multiply the other real numbers with complex numbers?

Comment: Can't see why do you need to do it, R is a real number already.

Comment: Yeah you're right

Answer (score 2):

The above answer is correct for certain wavelengths. For metals, especially for longer wavelengths, the refractive index is a complex number. But when the wavelength becomes shorter, to X-ray wavelength or even shorter, the metal becomes transparent, and might finally have a real refractive index. See [this](https://refractiveindex.info/) database.